# Newsletter webpart/component for Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, email, newsletter

I want to ask about newsletter webpart/component for Sharepoint 2013. Is there any. Have You see any good module with history of send news ?

Comment: One simple and quick way would be to create an announcement list or a custom list and set up the columns of your choice, add an alert to the list and all the employees, or to create a workflow that email everyone when a new list item is added.

Answer (score 1):

there are 3rd party options available for this

Free Web Part: [News Ticker Web Part in SharePoint 2013](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/News-Ticker-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx)
               [SharePoint Newsletter](http://spn.codeplex.com/)

Also check this option: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/de1e1e2e-ee1c-4b1a-876f-8dfe87de67c2/how-to-build-a-malling-list-system-in-sharepoint-2013-for-a-public-site-?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 1):

There is a SharePoint solution that fits your requirement - EnovaPoint's JungleMail:
http://www.enovapoint.com/junglemail/sharepoint-group-email/

This one is designed to send newsletters and has a history feature, if you enable it, all sent emails are logged. 
If you meant to use it to send news from certain SharePoint list, JungleMail can do that, you can set up rules to resolve content from your SharePoint, directly into the email body.

Comment: Here is the review of this solution on sharepoint-community.net: http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/review-of-junglemail-newsletter-and-group-email-solutio